# Visual Studio Code not opening c# files

Tags: visual-studio-code, c#

In Windows, if I double-click a C# cs file, or select "Open With Code" from the context menu, the file isn't opened in VS Code, even though it immediately appears in the "Recently Opened Files" list in VS Code.  I have the C# and PowerShell extensions installed and .PS1 files open fine either way.  I have also tried using "Open With" and setting "Always use this Program".

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you drag and drop the file in VSCode will it open? If you open the containing folder in VSCode as workspace will it show?

Comment: Hi.  Yes it will, to both.  Also if I load it directly from "Recently Opened" after it fails to load.  As far as I can tell, it's only opening from Explorer that doesn't work and only files for C#.